# Confusion in MATLAB filter roll off

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have the following code in matlab:

```
L = 10000;
Power = -100;
A = 10^0.5;
Fs = 25e6;
fc1 = 100;
fc2 = 1e3;
fc3 = 10e3;
fc4 = 100e3;
fc5 = 1e6;
a1 = 2*pi*fc1/Fs;
a2 = 2*pi*fc2/Fs;
a3 = 2*pi*fc3/Fs;
a4 = 2*pi*fc4/Fs;
a5 = 2*pi*fc5/Fs;

x = wgn(1,L,Power);
y1 = zeros(1,L);
y2 = zeros(1,L);
y3 = zeros(1,L);
y4 = zeros(1,L);
y5 = zeros(1,L);
y = zeros(1,L);
for i = 2:L,
    y1(i) = (1-a1)*y1(i-1) + a1*x(i);
    y2(i) = (1-a2)*y2(i-1) + a2*x(i)/A;
    y3(i) = (1-a2)*y3(i-1) + a3*x(i)/A^2;
    y4(i) = (1-a2)*y4(i-1) + a4*x(i)/A^3;
    y5(i) = (1-a2)*y5(i-1) + a5*x(i)/A^4;
    y(i) = y1(i) + y2(i) + y3(i) + y4(i) + y5(i);
end
fft1 = fft(y);
fft1 = fft1(1:length(y)/2+1);
psd1 = (1/(Fs*length(y)))*abs(fft1).^2;
psd1(2:end-1) = 2*psd1(2:end-1);
freq = 0:Fs/length(y):Fs/2;
figure(3);
semilogx(freq,10*log10(psd1))
grid on

Ts = 40e-9;
z = tf('z',Ts);
H1 = a1/(1-(1-a1)*z^-1);
H2 = (a2/A)/(1-(1-a2)*z^-1);
H3 = (a3/A^2)/(1-(1-a3)*z^-1);
H4 = (a4/A^3)/(1-(1-a4)*z^-1);
H5 = (a5/A^4)/(1-(1-a5)*z^-1);
H = (H1 + H2 + H3 + H4 + H5);
figure(5);
bode(H),grid
```

The intent of this code is to model flicker noise, which has 10dB/dec of slope in its power spectral density.
To model that there is a filter whose output is `y(i)` and input `x(i)` which is white guassian noise in this case. In the bode plot of the filter (labelled as figure 5) I can see that it has 10dB/dec of roll-off as I intended.
But when I check the output noise (y(i) in this case) power spectral density (labelled as figure 3) I am seeing 20dB/dec of roll-off.
Could someone please explain what I did wrong and why I am not able to get the 10dB roll-off in power spectral density?

Comment: It looks like it would be helpful for you to run this through the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bode plot uses a transfer function which is the sum of 5 similar subfilters, each using a coefficient a<sub>i</sub>. In your implementation, you should similarly have 5 subfilters with a regular structure. Howerver, while copying each line you have left some of the coefficients for `y3`, `y4` and `y5` to use `a2`. You should get your expected result by simply substituting the respective `a3`, `a4` and `a5` like so:

```
for i = 2:L,
    y1(i) = (1-a1)*y1(i-1) + a1*x(i);
    y2(i) = (1-a2)*y2(i-1) + a2*x(i)/A;
    y3(i) = (1-a3)*y3(i-1) + a3*x(i)/A^2;
    y4(i) = (1-a4)*y4(i-1) + a4*x(i)/A^3;
    y5(i) = (1-a5)*y5(i-1) + a5*x(i)/A^4;
    y(i) = y1(i) + y2(i) + y3(i) + y4(i) + y5(i);
end
```